# Android - how to return to original screen view after setContentView(img)

Tags: java, android

I have written an app which has a screen view containing a thumbnail that I want to expand to full screen view (with pan and zoom) when I click it.

The large view with pan an zoom works fine, but I want to return to the original view when I click the large image.

```
final TouchImageView imgBig = new TouchImageView(Dashboard.this);
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
final Bitmap bitmap = result.getImage();

img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imgBig.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imgBig.setMaxZoom(4f);
        setContentView(imgBig);
        imgBig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            // What do I need to do here to return to original thumbnail screen view?

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Have tried a number of things without success!

Comment: Just add another call to setContentView(R.<your_activity_xml>);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the original setContentView(R.layout.main) will set it back.

It might be better to have an ImageView in the layout xml and set its image and show and hide it. Otherwise you are stuck with just one view which may be limiting.

When you do a setContentView its initializing your activity with that content. So if you want to just put something on top of it you could just have a hidden view. In your layout xml code make an image view that sits on top of all the other views. Then set its visibility="gone" so its hidden. 
Then in your onClick instead of calling setContentView just set the image bitmap like you do and call imgBig.setVisibility(View.Gone or View.Visible) to show or hide your big image.

Another possibility is to have 2 activities. And call startActivity to show your big image and then finish to go back to the other activity like it was.

Another possibility is to use fragments, but that probably more involved.

Comment: That restores the original layout view, but I had populated it with data before the setContentView() call.  what I wanted to do was to return to the fully populated screen - i.e. somehow saving the state before the call?

Comment: I've gone for the startActivity route and it fixes the problem perfectly